# Changing console font on Ubuntu 10.04 Server

Tags: 10.04, server

How can I change local console font on Ubuntu 10.04 Server to `Inconsolata`?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it's not asking to set the console font to Ubuntu Mono like the linked question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Click through a bunch of questions in there, and one of the last ones
will be about the console font size.
 per this post here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server/2010-June/004262.html

Comment: Works for font size too. Handy when I was trying to setup Ubuntu on a Retina Mac.