# 15.10 Console font (Fixed)

Tags: fonts, console

I have noticed the console font change in 15.10 from Terminus (15.04 and previous) to Fixed. When Fixed is okay, it is quite ugly and Terminus was way better.

I'd like to know what the 'safest' way to install and use PERMANENTLY the Terminus font on 15.10 Consoles (TTY : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>).

I said 'safest' because I tried to install the Terminus font and just installing the font (I mean I hadn't even configure anything to actually use it) managed to mess my entire system font (i.e. nautilus changed its font, that's weird but that is what happened...)

Anyway, any help appreciated :p

Comment: Tried http://askubuntu.com/a/107577/158442?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

1. Used `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to pick the right font
2. The font is instantly changed
3. Rebooted. The font is back to Fixed but...
4. Tried `setupcon` to check my console font (if step 1 was 'successful')
5. If I see my font then it's ok (if not go step 1 and try again)
6. Edit `/lib/systemd/system/console-setup.service` to add at the end:
   `ExecStart=/bin/setupcon`
7. Now all my consoles use the font I picked (Terminus).

Found various infos here and there but mostly [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/how-do-i-permanently-change-the-console-tty-font-type-so-it-holds-after-reboot) and most credits should go to **MeetTitan**.

Et voilà !